# Selenium webdriver python element screenshot not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I looked up Selenium python documentation and it allows one to take screenshots of an element. I tried the following code and it worked for small pages (around 3-4 actual A4 pages when you print them):

```
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)

# Configure options for Firefox webdriver
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

# Initialise Firefox webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").screenshot("career.png")

driver.close()
```

When I try it with `url="https://waitbutwhy.com/2020/03/my-morning.html"`, it gives the screenshot of the entire page, as expected. But when I try it with `url="https://waitbutwhy.com/2018/04/picking-career.html"`, almost half of the page is not rendered in the screenshot (the image is too large to upload here), even though the "body" tag does extend all the way down in the original HTML.

I have tried using both implicit and explicit waits (set to 10s, which is more than enough for a browser to load all contents, comments and discussion section included), but that has not improved the screenshot capability. Just to be sure that selenium was in fact loading the web page properly, I tried loading without the `headless` flag, and once the webpage was completely loaded, I ran `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").screenshot("career.png")`. The screenshot was again half-blank.

It seems that there might be some memory constraints put on the `screenshot` method (although I couldn't find any), or the logic behind the `screenshot` method itself is flawed. I can't figure it out though. I simply want to take the screenshot of the entire "body" element (preferably in a `headless` environment).

Comment: You have attached 2 the same urls. Please share the page where you got the problem.

Comment: Done @AliaksandrPlekhau

Answer (score 1):

You may try this code, just that you need to install a package from command prompt using the command `pip install Selenium-Screenshot`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from Screenshot import Screenshot_Clipping


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://waitbutwhy.com/2020/03/my-morning.html")
obj=Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()
img_loc=obj.full_Screenshot(driver, save_path=r'.', image_name='capture.png')
print(img_loc)

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Outcome/Result comes out to be like, you just need to zoom the screenshot saved

[image: capture.png]

Hope this works for you!

Comment: It takes a _lot_ of time to take a screenshot of https://waitbutwhy.com/2018/04/picking-career.html

Comment: I also checked the quality. It's not quite sharp and is a flattened version of the actual HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def test_fullpage_screenshot():
    # please note that we MUST use headless mode
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    driver.get("your url")
    time.sleep(2)

    height = driver.execute_script('var pageHeight = 0;function findHighestNode(nodesList) {for (var i = nodesList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {if (nodesList[i].scrollHeight && nodesList[i].clientHeight) {var elHeight = Math.max(nodesList[i].scrollHeight, nodesList[i].clientHeight);pageHeight = Math.max(elHeight, pageHeight);}if (nodesList[i].childNodes.length) findHighestNode(nodesList[i].childNodes);}} findHighestNode(document.documentElement.childNodes);return pageHeight;')
    width  = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.scrollWidth')
    driver.set_window_size(width, height)  # the trick
    
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_fullpage_screenshot()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).